# How many calculations are performed per second on codechef?

Tags: performance

We can solve some problems by using the rule of the thumb of "10 million calculations are performed per second". I am interested in what machine is used by codechef to evaluate submissions and how many calculations does it perform per second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codechef uses SPOJ servers. The new problems use Cube cluster, as mentioned here- http://www.spoj.com/clusters/. I'd say it can run around O(10^8) computations in 1 sec.
Source -:
http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/35098/complexity-and-execution-time
http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/1544/how-many-approx-loops-are-allowed-in-1-sec-lime-limit